# Intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ with a positive distance

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

Given a countable collection of open intervals in $\mathbb{R}$, can you always make it so that (i) the intervals are disjoint (ii) all intervals have a positive minimum distance between them and (iii) have the same total measure (let's say it's finite to begin with)?

I was thinking yes because the first is a property of open sets in $\mathbb{R}$ and if they're already disjoint, then the second can be done because if $A$ and $B$ are intervals with 0 distance between them, then

$$\overline{A} \cap \overline{B} = \{x\}$$ a single point such that $$A \cup B \cup \{x\}$$ is now an open interval with the same measure.

Comment: if the intervals are given, then you can not prescribe anything.

Comment: What do you mean by "make it so that"?

Comment: @Thomas why can you not relabel them accordingly?

Comment: i.e. if I have $\{(1,2),(2,3),(5,6)\}$, then I change this into the collection $\{(1,3),(5,6)\}$ which is disjoint and of a positive distance between the sets

Comment: If the $n$th interval is $(a_n,b_n)$ abd you want an interval of length $\ell_{n+1}$ next, let if ve $(a_{n+1},b_{n+1})=(b_n+1mb_n+1+\ell_{n+1})$

Comment: @JohnDD What prevents you from changing itinto $\{(1,2),(2.1,3.1),(5,6)\}$?

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen The fact that I want the new intervals to be $A \cup B \cup \{x\}$ as above

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen does that not then determine it?

Comment: it's not about relabeling. It's about properties.

Comment: @JohnDD: You have to specify what are allowed and what are disallowed changes.  Otherwise I'll just discard all intervals from the collection and replace them by a collection of my choice. I doubt that this is what you had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

i)  Yes.  Since R is locally countable any open set is the union of open components which are intervals.  Since R is separable, there is countable many such intervals.

ii)  No.  (0,1) and (1,3) for example.

iii)  Yes, the measure of the union of the original sets will
be the same as the total of the measures of the disjoint sets.
Is that what you were asking?